# How do multiple dagger attacks work?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

My character just equipped a dagger for the first time and it looks as though regular attacks actually hit twice.

1. Is that just a visual effect, or are those actually two attacks?
2. What causes it? Does every dagger attack always behave this way?
3. Does each attack has a chance to apply on-hit debuffs separately from the other attack?